# Java server socket response to previouse connected client

Tags: java, sockets

I have a `Server` and two `clients`.

I have finished i/o with the `client A` and `client B` .

Now i need to reconnect to `Client A` and do some input/output with that client.

I store `connectedClientsHistory` in a list of String with their `ip` and `ports`.

But the problem is that i got Exception `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Here is my code:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

private static int serverPort = 9090;
private static ServerSocket listener;
private static int numberOfConnectedClients;
private static int numberOfPlayers;
List<String> orderOfConnectedClients = new LinkedList<String>();

public Server(int port) throws IOException {
    listener = new ServerSocket(port);
    this.serverPort = port;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Thread thread = new Server(9090);
    thread.start();
}

public void run() {

    while (numberOfConnectedClients < numberOfPlayers) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients on server Port " + listener.getLocalPort() + " ...\n");

            Socket connectedClient = listener.accept();
            numberOfConnectedClients++;

            System.out.println("Connected Client ip/port:   " + connectedClient.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
            orderOfConnectedClients.add(connectedClient.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
            System.out.println("History Connected Clients: " + orderOfConnectedClients);

            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());
            InputStream inFromClient = connectedClient.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromClient);


            if (numberOfConnectedClients == numberOfPlayers) {
                // notify to the first client

                String[] firstClient = orderOfConnectedClients.get(0).split(":");
                System.out.println(firstClient);

                Socket reconnectSocket = new Socket(firstIp, firstPort);
                DataOutputStream outToClient2 = new DataOutputStream(reconnectSocket.getOutputStream());
                outToClient2.writeUTF("Reconnect?");

         // how access to the first client?

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to edit your question a bit: *But the problem is that i got Exception* is a bit cryptic: What exception?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Sorry, see that again.

Comment: 'Now i need to reconnect to Client A and do some input/output with that client.' The problem is here. You are attempting the impossible. You can't do that in TCP. Clients connect to servers. Not the other way round. You state that you're 'finished I/O with client A' and then that you 'need to reconnect to client A'. You're contradicting yourself.Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I should correct that , two clients are connected now, now how send some data to the first client?

Comment: Err, via the Socket that's connected to it? What's the question now?

Comment: @EJP Two clients are now connected to the server, how But the last client is `client B` , Now How can i write something to the `client A` ?